# Get only code and not complete web using PHP curl in WP?

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, web-scraping

I have this simple code:

```
$theBody = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get('http://www.wordpress.org') );
print_r( $theBody );
die();
```

It is working, but instead of just echoing the source code it displays the page like as in iframe.

I guess I need to tell my script that I need to show it as a code and not generate the page.

How to do that?

Comment: So you really think, you can scrape the **source code** of any and all PHP sites?

Comment: When you say "source code", do you mean you're attempting to fetch the PHP code that generates the remote page, or simply the resultant HTML?

Comment: Yes, I want HTML generated source code. Like when you click right mouse button and select `View page source` from the context menu.

Comment: This is just a matter of formatting. Look into the `html_entities()` function of PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fetch any source code of a website then you can have a look at [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) this it is very easy to use in this case.
Example:

```
include('parsar.php'); // you will get from that website
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
echo $html;
```

Comment: What about the security. Is it safe? I am going to scrap websites with a lot of malware javascript, maybe even some java stuff that would like to install on my localhost. I don't have a virtual machine on my Windows so my question is the PHP Simple HTML DOM safe and only the generated html will be downloaded in the memory or it will try to execute the code?

Comment: Not sure but, this parser do not / can not parse javascript generated content.